# how to extend an element over the border of his parent

Tags: html, css

I have a few tabs like this one:

[image]

As you may notice, the selected tab (the first one) is separated by it's parent border.

How can I make the tab to go over the border so that it will have the same color as the container (which on the lower side)?

The CSS for the first tab look like this:

```
tab-active{
    float: left;
    background-image: url("../xyz.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #D4DFFA;
}
tab {
    float: left;
}
tab_container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

<div id="tab_container">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab-active">tab 1 selected</li>
        <li class="tab">tab 2 not selected</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are no other elements between the tab and the tab container.

**Update:**

The red area is the selected tab. The green area is another tab which is not selected. The light blue from the bottom is the separator between tabs and content. The dark blue from the bottom is the content area.

I want to connect the red area to the dark blue area so that I won't have a separator (parent border) between them.

Comment: I really didn't understand your question, but try assigning your active tab a higher `z-index`.  Not sure if that is what you need or not.

Comment: I tried `z-index`. But I to use `position:absolute` which will destroy my entire tab layout. I will update my question so that it will be clearer.

Comment: you could use `position:relative` too

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the HTML for the tab bar (at least the first couple of tabs) and the CSS related to the tab bar and tabs, not only the active one. A picture leaves everybody unnecesarily trying to guess your code

Comment: It almost sounds like you may want to change the z-index

Answer (score 0):

On the `ul`, put `overflow:visible;`

On the tab `li`, put `padding-bottom:10px;`  (or whatever depth you want)

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gm4agp5v/)